# How do you change the default location of all your data / cores under Solr?

Tags: solr

How do you change the default location of where your data is kept under Solr.
On an AWS setup everything I create goes into /var/solr/data
In what config file is this default location stored?
I'd like to point it at the /data directory which is a 100GB mounted hard drive.

Comment: It's going to be in your `solrconfig.xml`  file -- Depending on your installation, will determine where that file is.    An easier way (verified in two-index SOLR setup) is to create a smylink instead of the data directory ..  You can copy the files wherever you want them to be --  `cp /var/solr/data /data/solr/data` --  Then back up the file `mv /var/solr/data /var/solr/data_bk` Then create a symlibnk `ln -s /data/solr/data /var/solr/data`  ...

Comment: So, in essence, the system still *thinks* it's using `/var/solr/data` -- But *in reality* it's using your `/data/` 100GB mounted drive for physical file storage.

Comment: I have 4 collections and they each have their own solrconfig.xml. there are more under example directories and configsets... how do I know which is the main one?

Comment: The `solrconfig.xml` you have needs to be edited for EACH collection individually ..  And the server needs restarted after config is changed .. As well as running a re-index  ..

Comment: I tried the symbolic link and the service failed to start. I'm little out of my depth in troubleshooting this.

Comment: I rechecked the symlink ... fixed an issue there... and made solr the owner and group for all the files and folders.... still no luck. Get msg - Job for solr.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status solr.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: Well that took two attempts. Some how I ended up with data/data folder structure in my mv and linking. Fixed that. And permissions. Restarted service and things seem ok so far. Thanks @Zak

Comment: You should post that as an official answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from editing each `solrconfig.xml` for **each** collection (or index) there is a work around that I've come up with in past installations.

Instead of editing 4 files to point to the new location, it is easier to simply "trick" SOLR into storing on your mounted drive using a symlink.

You will *point* your SOLR directory to your mounted drive:

```
/var/solr/data -> /data/whatever/directory
```

Copy your SOLR files:

```
cp /var/solr/data /data/whatever/directory
```

Back up your current data:

```
mv /var/solr/data/ /var/solr/data_backup
```

Create you symink (target -> symlink):

```
ln -s /data/whatever/directory /var/solr/data
```

After all is said and done, you, probably need to repair permissions, setting ownership to SOLR and ensuring that the linking worked correctly.  Inside the `/var/solr` directory .. You can run a `ls -lah` and you should be able to see whether the link is correctly routed.  If it is not, it'll be highlighted in red on most Debian systems.  It should look something like:

```
 lrwxrwxrwx  1 solr solr   31 Apr 30  2021 data -> /data/whatever/directory
```

Once all finished up .. Restart the SOLR service and re-index your collections.